# difference between string array and integer array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

If i declare an array of strings then i can add this array to a `listbox` as follows:

```
 Dim a() As String = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
 ListBox1.Items.AddRange(a.ToArray)
```

But when i declare the same array as integer then  `ListBox1.Items.AddRange()` gives error for me

The code is

```
Dim a() As Integer = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(a.ToArray)
```

the error am getting is:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Sub AddRange(items() As Object)': 
     Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' 
     cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object' because 'Integer' is not a reference type.
    'Public Sub AddRange(value As System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)':
     Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.
```

i know i can add the array to list box using for loop but i wish to know how can i add an integer array to a `listbox` using `ListBox1.Items.AddRange()`

code for adding elements using `for`

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(a(i))
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read carefully you will see where the problem is:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of **Integer**'  cannot be converted to
>   '1-dimensional array of **Object**'  because **'Integer' is not a reference
>   type.**

So what you can do is first *box* the integers:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(a.Select(Function(i) CObj(i)).ToArray())
```

or a bit simpler:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(a.Cast(Of Object).ToArray())
```

#### Remark

In the end I think you will almost never need something like this, as you might wish to format your numbers somehow. So in most cases you will end up with something similar to:

```
dim formated = a.Select(Function(i) String.Format("number: {0}", i))
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(formated.ToArray())
```

anway and you don't have to concern yourself with the *reference* type detail.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation with example coding this is working fine for me

Answer (score -1):

Just use data-binding and set the `DataSource` property instead of adding the items directly.  In that case, anything that implements `IList` is OK.